# Count and Sum formula in non-numeric column MS Access query

Tags: sql, ms-access, count, sum

I have a table with a column `Tools`, which stores a string like "Card" or "Cash". I want to obtain a query that count the row if the `Tools` is Card and also to sum the result of the count.

I tried in this way, in the grid control I added Tools and "Card" in criteria and also this expression

```
NewField: Sum(Count([Tools]))
```

but MS Access throws an error about data type, because `Tools` isn't numeric.

I want to obtain it without using SQL, how can I do it?

Thanks

Comment: _ I want to obtain a query_ is incompatible with _I want to obtain it without usin Sql_ as queries use SQL.

Comment: I think isn't incompatible. I want to use the grid Ms access system to get a query.

Comment: I think you need a guide like "Beginning with Microsoft Access" to learn how Access works and is intended to be used.

Comment: I think you need a guide like "Beginning with good manners" to learn how to interact with people. If i decide not to use SQL view i have many reasons. I simply asked a question, If your response is not the right solution you can avoid writing.

Comment: Sorry if I offended you, that was not my intention, but your question and comments makes little sense, thus indicates that you miss some basic understanding of how Access works and how to work with Access. If that is not the case, please rephrase your question.

Answer (score 1):

Count and Sum seems the same here as the field only may hold "Card" once, so try:

```
NewField: Sum(IIf([Tools] = 'Card', 1, 0))
```

Comment: in this way the query ask me to insert a value to parameter "Tools". The Tools field is not numeric obviously. Any other hints?

Comment: If it asks for a value it means that your column is not called 'Tools' (MsAccess doesn't know what Tools is and assumes it is a parameter. It doesn't mean it is not numeric

Comment: My colum is called 'Tools' and the field is short text type. It ask for a parameter. I don't want to i sert a parameter. I just want the new column created by the expression. I want to use MS access' s grid instead of SQL view.